# Suggest https instead of http for links, when authoring a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, editor

When writing this question, if I go to insert a link, the default link suggestion is `http://`, should it be `https://`?

[image: Screenshot of this question being created!]

Comment: Not necessarily. There are many sites which aren't served through SSL. While we would love to have each and every site to be served through a secure connection, that will remain a desire for some time i'm afraid.

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder if we were to simply use `//example.com` (if that could be an additional feature request) as we would for when coding scripts like JS for instance, or CSS files where they would automatically propagate to either HTTP or HTTPS depending on the server's origin of posting. For instance, in using `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com` which if the server's origin is on HTTP it will fetch the equivalent URL or HTTPS respectively. Maybe this could be added to the question.

Comment: Plus, if you're referencing a link on the Stack Network, theoretically it should be HTTPS since there was an automatic bot that modified posts containing reference links on the network from HTTP to HTTPS. I wonder if that would still be the case if an HTTP URL were inserted and that it (the bot)  would go and detect it and automatically edit/modify the post. I realize that by using any HTTP URL on the network, that it automatically redirects to its HTTPS equivalent, am just wondering if what I wrote here would happen.

Comment: Does the text really affect people? Don't people just paste in the URL from some other tab? Are there any statistics that can show whether or not HTTP links are common? Does it even cause problems in the first place, since many HTTPS websites redirect to HTTPS anyway?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Protocol relative links are good. Unfortunately, for internal SO links, they are not recognized wrt. being placed in the "linked" area in the sidebar. I posted a [feature request to change such that they are recognized and placed in that section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291236/protocol-relative-and-relative-urls-should-be-considered-linked).

Comment: @beerwin Sites not served through TLS is becoming less and less common.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Whether the origin is HTTPS… what does that have to do with the link’s target? Stack Overflow is always served over HTTPS now anyway AFAIK.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that I know, thanks. I also mentioned something about if someone references a link on the Stack network using HTTP, if the bot will automatically change that to HTTPS, as it has done in the not too distant past.

Answer (score 15):

I copy and paste my links from another tab in their entirety, so you could put a bunch of gibberish there by default and it wouldn't affect me. I suspect it is not that big of a deal to most other people as well.

Comment: Indeed. Does *anyone* actually type directly into that box? I suspect it's in the single-digit percentages, or lower. The only advantage of the placeholder text is as a guideline ("oh, *that's* where I put the URL").

Comment: @CodyGray Agreed, but if so, it should be a **placeholder**, instead of a plain text

Comment: @Mistalis Some browsers do not support placeholder